# Banshee gets blocked and do nothing

Tags: banshee

I installed 11.10 on an Intel Pentium M processor 1.40GHZ, Memory 733.2 MiB, Disk 38.6GB, OStype 32 bit.

I live in Mozambique were downloading software is charged by MB and is very expensive.

Previously I downloaded 12.04 which cost around £10 but couldn't install it since it needs PaE and this PC doesn't have it.

So I spent another £10 to download 11.10.

---

We want to do 3 very simple things with the minimum data downloading:

1. Internet connection through the dongo -**Done**
2. Listen to music - From CD and from USB memory stick and hard disk
3. Watch a movie

First it doesn't recognize the CDs or mp3 on my hard drive or USB.  I downloaded and installed **ubuntu-restricted extras**, but the installation failed.

I tried to install it again from the terminal writing

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

It failed also, output below

**Output**

```
helio@helioPc:~$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras 
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done 
ubuntu-restricted-extras is already the newest
version. 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 440 not
upgraded. 
1 not fully installed or removed. After this operation, 0 B
of additional disk space will be used. 
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y 
Setting up flashplugin-installer (11.2.202.236ubuntu0.11.10.1) ...
Downloading...
--2012-08-10 10:18:36--  http://archive.canonical.com/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flashplugin_11.2.202.236.orig.tar.gz
Resolving archive.canonical.com... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address `archive.canonical.com' download failed 
The Flash plugin is NOT installed. dpkg: error processing flashplugin-installer
(--configure):  subprocess installed
post-installation script returned error exit status 1 
Errors were encountered while processing:  flashplugin-installer 
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

After this, I can listen to one song. I click on a song on my memory stick, banshee opens up, you can hear the song but banshee is completely blocked, you cannot do anything there, and when the song finish you cant close banshee it doesn't respond, let alone do a play-list.

Why does banshee get blocked? What do I need to do, without needing to download as I have to restart Ubuntu to kill the process?

---

**AVI and DVD playback**

If I try to open a AVI file from my memory stick, Movie player opens up but it gets completely blocked and I cannot close it. So I have to restart Ubuntu.

Comment: Welcome @toni.  can you describe better what you mean by "blocked"

Answer (score 3):

**Unfortunatately you will need to download addition codecs to play avi's and DVDs** or try a different player like VLC which may have the codecs you need.

---

**For DVD Play back**

You need to add the correct codecs for DVD Playback, They do not come with the Live Ubuntu CD

First Install the Medibuntu Repositories Medibuntu repository provides all the playback and encoding capabilities that most Windows and Mac systems contain, but which Ubuntu’s creators decline to include by default in their systems, due to licensing restrictions and a lack of open-source code for those features. If you just want to get AAC playback, copyright DVDs playing, and newer versions of all the audio, video, and font files, load Medibuntu into your system.

Open your Terminal (Ctrl-Alt-T), copy and paste these 3 lines (one at a time):

```
sudo wget --output-document=/etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list http://www.medibuntu.org/sources.list.d/$(lsb_release -cs).list && sudo apt-get --quiet update && sudo apt-get --yes --quiet --allow-unauthenticated install medibuntu-keyring && sudo apt-get --quiet update

sudo apt-get -y update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade

sudo apt-get install app-install-data-medibuntu apport-hooks-medibuntu
```

sudo wget --output-document=/etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list http://www.medibuntu.org/sources.list.d/$(lsb_release -cs).list && sudo apt-get --quiet update && sudo apt-get --yes --quiet --allow-unauthenticated install medibuntu-keyring && sudo apt-get --quiet update
sudo apt-get -y update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade
sudo apt-get install app-install-data-medibuntu apport-hooks-medibuntu

Then

If you are running a 32-bit version of Ubuntu, copy and paste in Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install w32codecs libdvdcss2

sudo apt-get install libdvdnav4

sudo apt-get install libdvdread4

sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/./install-css.sh
```

sudo apt-get install w32codecs libdvdcss2
sudo apt-get install libdvdnav4
sudo apt-get install libdvdread4
sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/./install-css.sh

If you are running a 64-bit version of Ubuntu, copy and paste in Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install w64codecs libdvdcss2

sudo apt-get install libdvdnav4

sudo apt-get install libdvdread4

sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/./install-css.sh
```

sudo apt-get install w64codecs libdvdcss2
sudo apt-get install libdvdnav4
sudo apt-get install libdvdread4
sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/./install-css.sh

Once Completed you will be able to play DVDs.

Comment: I will try to download VLC and see if it works better. I thought that ubuntu-restricted-extras will download all the codecs needed. Listening to music is the most important thing to my friend :). I have 2 more questions: 1- When i downloaded ubuntu-restricted-extras where was the file saved. I would like to copy in my external hard disk so i dont need to download it again. 2- Do i need to mount the cd/dvd reader? When i introduce a cd with music i am unable to see the cd and neither the content. If i need to how do i do it? Thanks

Comment: 3- Why Banshee is not working for us at all? When i open it just to look around Wherever i click it doesnt respond at all. Thanks